# Dirac's delta, infinite series and integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Why $\int_{-\infty}^x\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} p^{i-1}\delta(\alpha-i)d\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^x p^{i-1}\delta(\alpha-i)d\alpha$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac's delta and $p \in ]0;1[$ is a number ?

Why the infinite series and the integral they can be exchanged ?
Which theorems are involved ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $p$ a number or a function? If it is a number, then the integral is trivial ($\int \delta(\alpha -i)d\alpha = 1$ iff i is within the integration bounds).

Comment: @mousomer: Hi! Yes, $p$ is a number. But, it should not be $\int_{-\infty}^{x} \delta(\alpha -i)d\alpha = u(x-i)$ ? However, I've edited the post, because the question was not clear.

Comment: Dirac is not a function of a real variable, you can't integrate it with the usual definitions of integral : your question is not rigourous

Comment: Tryss, Dirac is a linear integral operator on the space of functions. It is defined as an object which gives you $\int f(x) \delta (x-x_0)dx = f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a number, you can push it out of the integral, and then it's a trivial theorem about discrete series.